# Unable to use sencha command to generate project ExtJs 5.1

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I am using extjs 5.1. As suggested [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/getting_started/getting_started.html) I have downloaded and installed `sencha cmd 5`

After issuing following command from terminal `sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app` I am getting errors as shown in below image. Please help

[image]

I installed the sencha exe @C:\Program Files\Sencha\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.2.52 on my box.

Answer (score 0):

`-sdk` flag should point to folder of the ExtJS framework, not to Cmd folder.

You have to download framework first or use remote version of the framework `sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app`

Comment: I ran `sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app` command first and got some error (error in the image attached with question). After that I tried using `-sdk` option. Do i need to separately download ExtJs framework  for using `-sdk` option? ??

Comment: Yes, you need to download ExtJs separately to use `-sdk` flag

Comment: What is the problem with the first command `sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app` ?

Comment: It's hard to say. It can be some JDK issue, try to update Java to last version